# How can I have the first row at the top and the second row vertically centered?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I'm using Bootstrap 5 and I'm trying to get the first row to be at the top of the page and the second row to occupy the rest of the viewport and have its content vertically centered without scrollbars (assuming the viewport is high enough).  Here's the basic code

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container min-vh-100">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-md-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-md-10">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row min-vh-100 align-items-center">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The second row does correctly center its content, however, because I'm using the min-vh-100 class it produces scroll bars (removing the first row makes the scroll bars go away as expected).  Changing the second row's min-vh-100 to h-100 class doesn't help (actually makes things worse).  The problem seems to be how to tell the second row to occupy 100% of the parent's remaining height and not 100% of the viewport height.

Comment: "Vertically centered" and "taking remaining space" aren't really the same thing. The former is positional and the latter refers to sizing. You should revise to clarify which you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `d-flex` and `flex-column` classes on your container. Then, rather than forcing height on the second row, use `flex-fill` to get it to use the remaining space. Fixed sizing should be a last resort.

See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex.

```css
.row:first-child {
  background: thistle;
}

.row:last-child {
  background: moccasin;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-2">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-10">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row flex-fill align-items-center">
    <div class="col-6">
      Content
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the Bootstrap container isn't a flexbox by default?  The rows are, so one would assume the container would be also.

Comment: I imagine because most sites don't try to fit into the viewport--row height is determined by content.